# Let $G=\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. Consider the quotient group $H=G/\langle (10,3,2)\rangle$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, smith-normal-form

Determine a direct product of cyclic groups that is isomorphic to $H$.

The Smith Normal form can be used to find the invariant factors in the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups. I set up the following matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 24 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 6 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 \\ 10 & 3 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$ but I was unable to find the SMF of this matrix.

I know the following about the structure of $H$:

$|\langle (10,3,2)\rangle|=12$

Also $|G|=24*6*3$ so by Lagrange's Theorem, $|H| = 36$.

By the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelain groups, $H$ may have the following structure:

$\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}$

$\mathbb{Z}/18\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

$\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$

$\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$

I am not sure how to identify the correct group structure without the invariant factors from the SMNF.

**Edit:** Here is some of my work by hand. Am I proceeding correctly?

\begin{align*}
  &\,
  \begin{pmatrix}
    24 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & 6 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 3 \\
    10 & 3 & 2
  \end{pmatrix}
  \sim
  \begin{pmatrix}
    10 & 3 & 2 \\
    24 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & 6 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 3
  \end{pmatrix}
  \sim
  \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 10 & 3 \\
    0 & 24 & 0 \\
    0 &  0 & 6 \\
    3 &  0 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}
  \\
  \sim&\,
  \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 10 &  1 \\
    0 & 24 &  0 \\
    0 &  0 &  0 \\
    3 &  0 & -3
  \end{pmatrix}
  \sim
  \begin{pmatrix}
     1 & 2 & 10 \\
     0 & 0 & 24 \\
     0 & 0 &  0 \\
    -3 & 3 &  0
  \end{pmatrix}
  \sim
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 10 \\
    0 & 0 & 24 \\
    0 & 0 &  0 \\
    0 & 9 & 30
  \end{pmatrix}
  \\
  \sim&\,
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 &  0 \\
    0 & 0 & 24 \\
    0 & 0 &  0 \\
    0 & 9 & 30
  \end{pmatrix}
  \sim
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 &  0 \\
    0 & 9 & 30 \\
    0 & 0 & 24 \\
    0 & 0 &  0
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

(Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyXbU.jpg).)

Comment: What are the difficulties you had trying to find the Smith normal form?

Comment: Did you try to find the normal form?

Comment: The numbers I end up with on the diagonal are too large, (product exceeds 36)

Comment: I think R1C3 to R2C1 looks wrong (dropped the 6).  Also, the final matrix in your calculation isn't yet in normal form...

Comment: Dropping the 6 was my mistake. I was able to reach the Smith normal form. Thanks @Daniel Schepler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Smith Form has diagonal entries 1, 3, 12 so that the quotient is isomorphic to $Z_3\times Z_{12}$.